# How to adjust canvas container based on user input?

Tags: html5-canvas

I have a canvas with some tools and it is within a div. How do I make the div adjust automatically based on user's input of the canvas width and height?

```
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="theCanvas" width="<?php echo $_POST['inputwidth'] ?>" height="<?php echo $_POST['inputheight'] ?>"></canvas>
<div class="tools">
<span class="icon"> 
    <button id="brushTool"></button>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I've tried setting min-height and min-width but it didn't work. The border of the container followed the size of the browser. Is it possible if I put max-height/width as php + a certain margin? Thanks guys! =)

```
#container{
    border-right: dotted black 5px;
    border-left: dotted black 5px;
    border-top: dotted black 5px;
    border-bottom: dotted black 5px;
    margin: auto;
}

#theCanvas {
    border: solid black 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: crosshair;
}
```

Comment: Can help with an answer that uses Javascript but are you looking for an answer that just uses HTML and CSS?

Comment: As of now, I'm willing to try anything. So, yes Javascript would be great. =) Thanks.

Comment: Hi, jing3142. Could you guide me with using Javascript? It would mean the world to me. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to take so long in responding, hope you have already found an answer.

Once you know the width and height of the Canvas in pixels you can use

```
CVW=document.getElementById("theCanvas").width;
CVH=document.getElementById("theCanvas").height;

CNW=CVW/0.6 //(for a 20% left and right margin given to the canvas)
CNH=CVH+40  //(for a 20px top and bottom margin given to the canvas)
document.getElementById("container").style.width=CNW+"px";
document.getElementById("container").style.height=CNH+"px";
```

You will need to put this in a function and only call it when you know width and height of canvas.

Note that width and height for container are set using css styles, but not for the canvas.

A full simplified version below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #container{
                border-right: dotted black 5px;
                border-left: dotted black 5px;
                border-top: dotted black 5px;
                border-bottom: dotted black 5px;
                margin: auto;
            }

            #theCanvas {
                border: solid black 5px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                background: #ffffff;
                margin-left: 20%;
                margin-top: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                cursor: crosshair;
            }
        </style>
        <script>

            function set() {
                CVW=document.getElementById("theCanvas").width;
                CVH=document.getElementById("theCanvas").height;

                CNW=CVW/0.6; //(for a 20% left and right margin given to the canvas)
                CNH=CVH+40;  //(for a 20px top and bottom margin given to the canvas)
                document.getElementById("container").style.width=CNW+"px";
                document.getElementById("container").style.height=CNH+"px";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="set()">
        <div id="container">
            <canvas id="theCanvas" width=200 height="300"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```